# Get the selected value from a stored function in a PLSQL block

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a stored pl/sql block which I need to run, the block calls a stored function and gets a returned value.

the function (using a SELECT) selects a value from a table, and returns a numeric value of 0 or 1 if the function ran successfully. the value selected from the table ranges from 0 to 100.
So when I run the block in SQLDeveloper I get either 1 or 0, but when I run the function from outside the block I get the values in range.

when I run

```
fetch_db_hit_ratio(1)
```

I get a value in range. But when I run the block

```
"DECLARE  
 RetVal NUMBER; 
BEGIN  
 RetVal := fetch_db_hit_ratio(1); 
END;  
"
```

I get either 0 or 1, I know I actually read the retVal, but how do I read the value selected by the function ?

here is a abbreviated function code

```
create or replace function    fetch_db_hit_ratio (dummy in number) return  number is
SUCCESS constant int :=0;
FAILURE constant int :=1;
errcode number:=NULL;
errmsg varchar2(1000) :=NULL;
step varchar2(1000) := 'some_text';
begin

begin
    select values(a) from some_table where condition;
exception
    when NO_DATA_FOUND then NULL;
end;

exception
when others then
    errcode:=sqlcode;
    errmsg:=substr(sqlerrm,1,100);
    --rp_message(errcode,errmsg,step,3);
    return -1;
end;
```

Comment: Please add definition (at least simplified) of function fetch_db_hit_ratio.

Comment: I've a added the a simplified code

Comment: Is your question "*how do I read the value **using JDBC**?*" or is your question "*how do I read the value **from within another PL/SQL procedure**?*"

Comment: the selected value of a stored function within a PL/SQL block

Comment: So why did you add the `java` and `jdbc` tags?

Comment: can you pls post the sample data, and expected output ? what do you mean by "I get a value in range."

Comment: the stored function by it's logic should return a number between 0 and 100, that's the range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I see 2 options - either function returns record with 2 values:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ret_val_type AS RECORD(
  func_result NUMBER,
  sql_result NUMBER
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fetch_db_hit_ratio (dummy IN NUMBER)
return rev_val_type
```

or create function with out parameter:

```
create or replace function fetch_db_hit_ratio (dummy in number, sql_result out number)
return number
```

Comment: in the second code snippet, are you saying i should put the "sql_result out number" as an argument to the function, why is that ?

Comment: To return more than one value from function. For example:

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ret_test(p_dummy IN NUMBER, p_sql_result OUT NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO p_sql_result
  FROM (SELECT * FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <10);
  RETURN 1;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN 0;
END;
/

DECLARE
  v_ret_val NUMBER;
  v_sql_val NUMBER;
BEGIN
  v_ret_val := ret_test(1, v_sql_val);
  dbms_Output.put_Line(v_ret_val);
  dbms_Output.put_Line(v_sql_val);
END;
/`